# QML blur effect

Tags: qt, qml

I want whole screen must be blured beside centre.
How can I make it?

```
FastBlur
{
    x: 0
    y: 0
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    source: video
    radius: 100
}
```

// I want this square without blur

```
Rectangle
{
    x: 100
    y: 100
    height: 250
    width: 250
    color: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image
    {
        id:img
        source:"qrc:/Tulips.jpg"
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false
    }

    FastBlur
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: img
        radius: 100
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id:rect
        height: 250
        width: 250
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color:"red"
    }
}
```

Comment: no no, my fastblur source is videooutput and centre must be clear

Answer (score 0):

Use z values?

```
Window {
    Rectangle {
        z: 0
        id: blurred_background
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    FastBlue {
        z: 1
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: blurred_background
    }
    Rectangle {
        z: 2
        id: nonblurred_foreground
        height: 250
        width: 250
    }
}
```

Replace the rectangles with whatever item you want!
And make sure to not ignore the warning in the documentation that [blur cannot blur a parent of itself as source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-gaussianblur.html#source-prop)!